# What is the economic situation in Iran?

Tags: self-study, research

I recently investigated a bit about the Iranian economy and did not get an interesting result:

- Iran's currency dropped to worst low in four decades
  (Since the Islamic Revolution in Iran).
- Transferring money in Iran is very difficult and sometimes impossible.
- Most countries of the world have declined from banking transactions with Iran.

Catastrophic!، right!?

What is the economic situation in Iran?

Comment: It is hard to assess Iran's economic situation considering that it has been under sanctions for sometime. No need for doing research, I hope you got the point. I would not even bother askigng this question. Are you sure it is a good question? Also, what is your definition of an "interesting result"?